# Is there a good string pluralization library for actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I haven't found a good library actionscript library for this yet.

I want to do things like:

```
Inflection.pluralize( "cat" ) == "cats"
Inflection.pluralize( "fish" ) == "fish"
```

I know ruby on rails has a library like this build in; and javascript has a really nice one as well: http://code.google.com/p/inflection-js/.

Any one know of a similar thing for actionscript?

Comment: if you have the source in javascript, it should be pretty easy to port it into as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google says:
http://kuwamoto.org/2007/12/17/improved-pluralizing-in-php-actionscript-and-ror/

```
package
{
public class Inflect
{
    private static var plural : Array = [
        [/(quiz)$/i,                     "$1zes"],
        [/^(ox)$/i,                      "$1en"],
        [/([m|l])ouse$/i,                "$1ice"],
        [/(matr|vert|ind)ix|ex$/i,       "$1ices"],
        [/(x|ch|ss|sh)$/i,               "$1es"],
        [/([^aeiouy]|qu)y$/i,            "$1ies"],
        [/(hive)$/i,                     "$1s"],
        [/(?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$/i,       "$1$2ves"],
        [/(shea|lea|loa|thie)f$/i,       "$1ves"],
        [/sis$/i,                        "ses"],
        [/([ti])um$/i,                   "$1a"],
        [/(tomat|potat|ech|her|vet)o$/i, "$1oes"],
        [/(bu)s$/i,                      "$1ses"],
        [/(alias|status)$/i,             "$1es"],
        [/(octop)us$/i,                  "$1i"],
        [/(ax|test)is$/i,                "$1es"],
        [/(us)$/i,                       "$1es"],
        [/s$/i,                          "s"],
        [/$/i,                           "s"]
    ];

    private static var singular : Array = [
        [/(quiz)zes$/i,             "$1"],
        [/(matr)ices$/i,            "$1ix"],
        [/(vert|ind)ices$/i,        "$1ex"],
        [/^(ox)en$/i,               "$1"],
        [/(alias|status)es$/i,      "$1"],
        [/(octop|vir)i$/i,          "$1us"],
        [/(cris|ax|test)es$/i,      "$1is"],
        [/(shoe)s$/i,               "$1"],
        [/(o)es$/i,                 "$1"],
        [/(bus)es$/i,               "$1"],
        [/([m|l])ice$/i,            "$1ouse"],
        [/(x|ch|ss|sh)es$/i,        "$1"],
        [/(m)ovies$/i,              "$1ovie"],
        [/(s)eries$/i,              "$1eries"],
        [/([^aeiouy]|qu)ies$/i,     "$1y"],
        [/([lr])ves$/i,             "$1f"],
        [/(tive)s$/i,               "$1"],
        [/(hive)s$/i,               "$1"],
        [/(li|wi|kni)ves$/i,        "$1fe"],
        [/(shea|loa|lea|thie)ves$/i,"$1f"],
        [/(^analy)ses$/i,           "$1sis"],
        [/((a)naly|(b)a|(d)iagno|(p)arenthe|(p)rogno|(s)ynop|(t)he)ses$/i,  "$1$2sis"],
        [/([ti])a$/i,               "$1um"],
        [/(n)ews$/i,                "$1ews"],
        [/(h|bl)ouses$/i,           "$1ouse"],
        [/(corpse)s$/i,             "$1"],
        [/(us)es$/i,                "$1"],
        [/s$/i,                     ""]
    ];

    private static var irregular : Array = [
        ['move'   , 'moves'],
        ['foot'   , 'feet'],
        ['goose'  , 'geese'],
        ['sex'    , 'sexes'],
        ['child'  , 'children'],
        ['man'    , 'men'],
        ['tooth'  , 'teeth'],
        ['person' , 'people']
    ];

    private static var uncountable : Array = [
        'sheep',
        'fish',
        'deer',
        'series',
        'species',
        'money',
        'rice',
        'information',
        'equipment'
    ];

    public static function pluralize( string : String ) : String
    {
        var pattern : RegExp;
        var result : String;

        // save some time in the case that singular and plural are the same
        if (uncountable.indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) != -1)
          return string;

        // check for irregular singular forms
        var item : Array;
        for each ( item in irregular )
        {
            pattern = new RegExp(item[0] + "$", "i");
            result = item[1];

            if (pattern.test(string))
            {
                return string.replace(pattern, result);
            }
        }

        // check for matches using regular expressions
        for each ( item in plural)
        {
            pattern = item[0];
            result = item[1];

            if (pattern.test(string))
            {
                return string.replace(pattern, result);
            }
        }

        return string;
    }

    public static function singularize( string : String ) : String
    {
        var pattern : RegExp;
        var result : String

        // save some time in the case that singular and plural are the same
        if (uncountable.indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) != -1)
            return string;

        // check for irregular singular forms
        var item : Array;
        for each ( item in irregular )
        {
            pattern = new RegExp(item[1] + "$", "i");
            result = item[0];

            if (pattern.test(string))
            {
                return string.replace(pattern, result);
            }
       }

       // check for matches using regular expressions
       for each ( item in singular)
       {
            pattern = item[0];
            result = item[1];

            if (pattern.test(string))
            {
                return string.replace(pattern, result);
            }
       }

       return string;

    }

    public static function pluralizeIf(count : int, string : String) : String
    {
        if (count == 1)
            return "1 " + string;
        else
            return count.toString() + " " + pluralize(string);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 Thank you for adding the code for history, should have done it myself but was late here and I was tired.